# Puppet concatenate list conditionally

Tags: puppet

I try to only deploy fail2ban Apache jails if apache is actually installed. I have a fact for that that works.

```
  # fail2ban
  $jails = [
      'ssh', 'ssh-ddos',
      'pam-generic'
  ] + if $f2b_enable_apache { ['apache-auth', 'apache-badbots', 'apache-multiport', 'apache-noscript', 'apache-overflows'] }

  notify{"Enable apache jails: ${f2b_enable_apache}":}
  notify{"Jails: ${jails}":}

  class { 'fail2ban':
    package_ensure => 'latest',
    jails => $jails
  }
```

When I run it though, then I get the follwing output

Without apache:

```
Puppet : Enable apache jails: false
Puppet : Jails: [ssh, ssh-ddos, pam-generic, apache-auth, apache-badbots, apache-multiport, apache-noscript, apache-overflows]
```

With apache:

```
Puppet : Enable apache jails: true
Puppet : Jails: [ssh, ssh-ddos, pam-generic, apache-auth, apache-badbots, apache-multiport, apache-noscript, apache-overflows]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it in both cases appended? Is there a better way to achieve this that is extensible?

Comment: One problem was that the true/false fact was not a bool but a string 'true' or 'false' ...

Answer (score 1):

I would likely use a [selector expression](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.3/lang_conditional.html#lang_condition_selector) for this:

```
$jails = $f2b_enable_apache ? {
  true  => ['ssh', 'ssh-ddos', 'pam-generic', 'apache-auth', 'apache-badbots', 'apache-multiport', 'apache-noscript', 'apache-overflows'],
  false => ['ssh', 'ssh-ddos', 'pam-generic'],
}
```

There are indeed algorithms for using `Array[String]` concatenation here, but they become messy due to Puppet DSL enforcing the immutability of variables. This uses one variable, one conditional expression, and no lambda iterator functions.